# Sending Hex string to TCP Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am connecting VideoJet Printer to my PC using TCP/IP, creating C# windows dekstop application to read and write TCP Socket. When I am semding below Hex String using hercules software [When HEX Checkbox tick] it is responding but when I am sending same hex string from my C# code it is not reponding
Please suggest me where I am doing wrong in my code

[image: Hercules Reponse]

```
try
        {
            client = new TcpClient("192.168.2.1", Convert.ToInt32("3001"));

            // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
            Byte[] data = HexString2Bytes(richTextBox3.Text);
            stream = client.GetStream();

            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}",richTextBox3.Text);

            // Receive the TcpServer.response.
            data = new Byte[65000];
            var readStream = new MemoryStream();
            int readBytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            while (readBytes > 0)
            {
                readStream.Write(data, 0, readBytes);
                readBytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            var responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readStream.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errormsg = ex.ToString();
        }


private byte[] HexString2Bytes(string hexString)
    {
        //check for null
        if (hexString == null) return null;
        //get length
        int len = hexString.Length;
        if (len % 2 == 1) return null;
        int len_half = len / 2;
        //create a byte array
        byte[] bs = new byte[len_half];
        try
        {
            //convert the hexstring to bytes
            for (int i = 0; i != len_half; i++)
            {
                bs[i] = (byte)Int32.Parse(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception : " + ex.Message);
        }
        //return the byte array
        return bs;
    }
```

Command Hex String
A503CA002C000000E4411251C0000000B60000003C0050006100720061006D0073003E00200020003C0043006F006C002000690064003D00220044006500760069006300650073002F0050004800640073002F0031002F005000720069006E00740049006E0066006F0072006D006100740069006F006E002200200067006500740046006C006100670073003D002200320022002000670065007400440065007000740068003D0022002D003100220020002F003E003C002F0050006100720061006D0073003E000000

Comment: Are you sending that data as text or actual bytes? I'm assuming the former since you're having issues and nowhere in your code you seem to convert the hex into bytes. So convert and send the actual data, not the text. For converting you can quickly find code with your favorite search engine.

Comment: See my updates question I have tried converting hex string to Hex Bytes and sent to TCP Socket but the response I get is "?." instead of response as in Hercules

Comment: It looks like with hercules there is a start character 'Z' and it is closing the connection at end.

Comment: Command line in Pink is what I have send and rest lines in black are the response

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know, why you have to make a While loop. when you received number of bytes from Server `readBytes`, so you could finish a code with Encoding like this:

```
string responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data,0,readbytes);
```

To get more information, you can find in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=net-5.0